# Power BI Tabular Sort Order

Tags: powerbi

Test driving MS Power BI Designer.  In the Tabular visualization I can't find way to maintain data source order.  I have a specific order I want a text field to be in.  It is sorted that way in query but report only allows asc/desc order.  Don't want to put 01,02,03 in text field.  Also don't want to include "order" field in the visualization. (That would work if I could "hide" field though). Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

This is a capability that is on the roadmap.  If you use Excel, you can see the 'sort by' option in Power Pivot.  The same capability will come to Power BI Designer, but it's not there yet.

Appreciate your using Power BI,
-Lukasz

- http://dev.powerbi.com
- http://blogs.msdn.com/powerbidev
- Make a feature request: https://support.powerbi.com/forums/265200-power-bi
- Sign up for Power BI: http://www.powerbi.com

Answer (score 1):

There's a way to do this in Power BI Desktop. Check this video at about 10:50.

https://youtu.be/d2bZpNZ6uIA?t=10m50s

You'll need to create another column of number values to tell it what order to sort the text values in. You can do that with "Enter Data" if it doesn't already exist.